# How to substitute '\N' in a string using python as it is leading to unicodeescape error?

Tags: python, regex, unicode-escapes

```
import re

import string

a= """  Message-ID: <13505866.1075863688222.JavaMail.evans@thyme>
Date: Mon, 23 Oct 2000 06:13:00 -0700 (PDT)
From: phillip.allen@enron.com
To: randall.gay@enron.com
Subject: 
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-From: Phillip K Allen
X-To: Randall L Gay
X-cc: 
X-bcc: 
X-Folder: \Phillip_Allen_Dec2000\Notes Folders\'sent mail
X-Origin: Allen-P
X-FileName: pallen.nsf

Randy,

 Can you send me a schedule of the salary and level of everyone in the 
scheduling group.  Plus your thoughts on any changes that need to be made.  
(Patti S for example)

Phillip

""" <br>
s=re.sub('[\\\]+', ' yy', a)
print(s)
```

error message:unicodeescape' decode can't decode bytes in position 354-355:malformed [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0MBe.png)\N character space

I've already tried using different combinations of backslashes but its still showing the same error

Answer (score 1):

To encode a literal backslash in a regex, you need four backlashes in a normal string (or two backslashes in a raw string), not three:

```
s = re.sub('\\\\+', ' yy', a)
```

or

```
s = re.sub(r'\\+', ' yy', a)
```

You don't need a character class for a single character (although it doesn't hurt much, either).

Comment: It bothers me to no end, but lots of people use character classes to escape meta-characters. Of course this won't work with backslashes which are meta-character both inside and outside character classes.

Comment: I've already used this before but still couldn't get the desired result. It's still giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that leads to your error message (which occurs during compile time, long before the also faulty regex is constructed (see my other answer)) is in this line:

```
X-Folder: \Phillip_Allen_Dec2000\Notes Folders\'sent mail
```

Here you have a `\N` that Python tries to interpret as an escape sequence like `"\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA}"`, and of course fails doing so.

You need two backslashes to correct that problem.

```
X-Folder: \\Phillip_Allen_Dec2000\\Notes Folders\\'sent mail
```

Comment: I understand the conflict that compiler faces at that particular position and it can be handled manually by substituting '\\' in place of '\' but I've been working on a project where I need to analyze thousands of emails in that particular format. So now I can't manually edit every email and hence if you could suggest a better way for this. Although thanks for considering my question and replying back.

Comment: The problem only occurs if you paste the email into the source code of your script. If you read it from a file, the backslashes will be recognized as such.